# How to prevent mobile keyboard from closing when I click button in website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, android-softkeyboard

I have a simple chat view, and one button that when clicked sends the value of input field to api (send message)

After I insert text via mobile virtual keyboard, and click "Send" Button the keyboard closes.

I want to prevent that closing, so user can send more messages and only when they click outside keyboard it finally closes

My react code is like this:

component.tsx

```
<span className="input-group-btn">
            <button
                 ref={submitMessageBtn}
                 className="btn"
                 onClick={React.useCallback((event) => {
                 event.nativeEvent.preventDefault();
                   sendMessage();
                 }, [])}
                 >
                      {i18n.sendMsgBtn}
                  </button>
                </span>


// somewhere down the function sendMessage
function sendMessage() {
        const messageContent = chatMessageInput.current!.value;
        chatMessageInput.current!.value = '';
        submitMessageBtn.current!.disabled = true;

        p.sendMessage(user.id, messageContent).catch((err) => {
            // not interesting for question
        });
    }
```

I tried in the button event handler to `preventDefault()` but doesn't work. I also tried `event.nativeEvent.stopPropagation();` `event.stopPropagation()` still no success. I don't understand why the keyboard closes (maybe due to losing focus but I want to keep it open)
How to stop mobile (android) virtual keyboard from closing, when I click this button ?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://codepen.io/EtienneLem/pen/GMgpmW) codepen can help you.

Comment: Interesting solution @Samball, works on my mobile device

Comment: I tried after posting here also doing `        submitMessageBtn.current!.focus()` and seem to work on Android, but issue is mobile keyboard is covering bottom of chat list. Need to padd dynamically based on size of keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question ranked high on google, and here is how I managed to do this (with the composition api)

you will need first to get a ref to your textarea (or input), and when you are firing the click event, call this ref value and focus on it:

```js
<template>
  <textarea
    ref="input"
    placeholder="Message..."
  />
  <button @click="sendMessage">Send</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { reactive, ref } from "vue";

// if you are using JS, write only const input = ref(null);
const input = ref<null | { focus: () => null }>(null);

async function sendMessage() {
  // keep focus back on the input
  input.value?.focus();
  // input.value.focus(); in JS

  // then send the message
  // ...
}
</script>
```

this was tested only on android though

Comment: Hi, I just read your answer and tested it on my android phone. It works good, thank you. I was writing also in my question that somehow the input loses focus and still did not focus it manually to avoid this. Good workaround and I hope in the future browsers will add more features so we can provide more app-like experience in the websites

Answer (score 4):

I had the same Problem with a Button in Vue.js and .preventDefault() on the click-event didn't help. The solution was adding an EventListener on the Button for the "touchend" Event.

```
mounted() {
this.guestName = "";

const btn = document.querySelector(".input-button");
if (btn){
  btn.addEventListener("touchend", (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    //functions for the Button need to be called here
    this.addGuestClicked(this.guestName);
  })
}
```

I just tested it on iOS, but I guess Android will work too.

Comment: This worked for me too. Or in my case, `onTouchEnd()`

Answer (score -1):

You can try the VirtualKeyboard API: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/virtual-keyboard/

```
if ('virtualKeyboard' in navigator) {
  // The VirtualKeyboard API is supported!
  navigator.virtualKeyboard.overlaysContent = true;
  navigator.virtualKeyboard.show();
  // When you want to hide it
  navigator.virtualKeyboard.hide();
}
```

Note this only works in a secure context i.e. `localhost` or https site. If you need to do testing and you want to host from your local device but test on your phone, use port forwarding as described here:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/local-server/

Also your browser MUST be focused on an element which is editable, as per the W3C spec. https://www.w3.org/TR/virtual-keyboard/#webidl-65390189

Comment: Never mind. This doesn't work, and I have no idea why :(